# Coreos: Trace etcd rejected connection source

Tags: ssl

I have a coreos instance with etcd-member enabled.

In the logs, I received a bunch of requests with source ports increased by 2 each time. IMHO that looks like a program that is checking to find a valid source address to be accepted.

How can I trace down where they came from and what service that is? This is my iptables config, so I'm assuming its something local:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
```

This is the output of the etcd journal:

```
Oct 27 14:40:02 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:40:02.810784 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40162" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:40:02 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:40:02.808002 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40158" (error "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:39:58 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:39:58.734359 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40156" (error "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:39:58 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:39:58.734101 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40152" (error "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:39:53 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:39:53.727212 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40148" (error "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:39:53 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:39:53.726941 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40144" (error "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:39:53 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:39:53.682223 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40138" (error "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:39:53 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:39:53.681992 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40136" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:39:48 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:39:48.719532 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40132" (error "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:39:48 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:39:48.719305 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40128" (error "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake", ServerName "")
Oct 27 14:39:48 <HOSTNAME> etcd-wrapper[924]: 2018-10-27 14:39:48.602150 I | embed: rejected connection from "127.0.0.1:40124" (error "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake", ServerName "")
```

Comment: "127.0.0.1" is local (it's localhost)

Comment: I know, but how can I find out which service is causing that request? `sudo lsof -i :41722` doesnt return me anything. So I believe its just there for a moment and closes and restarts at new port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging around, I found out that this is caused by flannel which is misconfigured.